# Mount Windows network share on Linux Container with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a selection of images that are on a Windows network share that I want to be accessible in my Linux container. I have tried adding the images as a volume in `docker-compose.yml` as below.

```
version: "3"
services: 
  GetImages.www:
    container_name: GetImages.www
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ../src/:/var/www/vhosts/GetImages/src/
      - I:\Path\To\Images\On\Network\:/var/www/vhosts/GetImages/PresenterImages
```

With the above, `docker-compose up` returns this error.

```
Cannot start service GetImages.www: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/uC/server/share/Path/To/Images/On/Network': mkdir /host_mnt/uC: operation not permitted.
```

I tried creating an `.env` file in the same directory as `docker-compose.yml` that contained the option `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` but it made no difference to the error message.

Interestingly, when attempting `docker-compose up` docker attempts to share a directory on the local C: drive that matches the UNC path to the server share instead of the UNC path itself. To elaborate, the UNC path is `\\server\share\Path\To\Images\On\Network`, and in Docker Desktop > Resources > File Sharing, a path is added `C:\server\share\Path\To\Images\On\Network`.

What do I need to do to make this network share accessible from within my docker container?

Comment: If you remember the solution, can you please add that as an answer?

Comment: @Arjan I never got it sorted and we went a different way with the project anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternate syntax you can use to mount volumes, which seems to work better:

```
version: "3"
services: 
  GetImages.www:
    container_name: GetImages.www
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: ..\src
          target: /var/www/vhosts/GetImages/src/
        - type: bind
          source: I:\Path\To\Images\On\Network\
          target: /var/www/vhosts/GetImages/PresenterImages
```

This uses the slightly older functionality of [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) but seems to work ok.

Comment: "bind source path does not exist" :(